# Youtube API get video duration from the XML

Tags: xml, api, parsing, youtube

Consider Youtube API XML files like http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$id
One particular XML data file is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/GI6CfKcMhjY
The following function gets the title of the video according to the XML url:

```
function ytTitle($ytid,$ytURLConstant){
    $url = $ytURLConstant.$ytid;
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load($url);
    echo $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

As I see there is video duration in the XML file:

```
<media:title type='plain'>Jack Sparrow (feat. Michael Bolton)</media:title><yt:duration seconds='197'/>
```

As I am an XML newbie any help concerning getting the video duration will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Youtube API and I find this very helpful site

http://viewsboard.com/boards/view/discussion/2/263