# are there any tools/scripts for analyzing/retrieving flash/html5 video information/metadata

Tags: perl, video, metadata

I want to play youtube video with a certain resolution, like 360p
and capture the packets, and then extract the video from the packets
and then I want to analyzing/retrieving flash/html5 video information/metadata from these videos
BTW, are videos still with the same resolution when they are extracted from the captured packets?

note that these videos may not be complete

are there any good tools for analyzing/retrieving flash/html5 video information/metadata
like video bit rate, video resolution(like 360p, 480p), used audio/video codecs, video size and duration/duration 
if the video is not complete, the information would ideally include the original video size, the actual video size, the original video length/duration and the actual video length/duration

I hope it is a script, if it is a tool. I hope it can be run through shell using command line coz I want automation.

A paper says perl could do this, but I don't how
thanks!

Comment: Have you took a look at search.cpan.org ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(long comment, not a complete answer)

IANAL, but your goals may not fit the [YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms?gl=US&hl=en):

Section 4. C

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

Section 4. H

> You agree not to use or launch any automated system, including without limitation, "robots," "spiders," or "offline readers," that […] sends more request messages to the YouTube servers […] than a human can reasonably produce in the same period by using a conventional on-line web browser. Notwithstanding the foregoing, YouTube grants the operators of public search engines permission to use spiders to copy materials from the site for the sole purpose of and solely to the extent necessary for creating publicly available searchable indices of the materials, but not caches or archives of such materials. […]

You may be able to access the required information directly using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api). Here is a [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference), and here is a [list of directly supported programming languages](https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#client_libraries). Perl will work as well, as the underlying data format is plain XML or JSON.

You might also find these SO questions [YouTube Player API: How to get duration of a loaded/cued video without playing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2086260/1521179) and [Youtube API get video duration from the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378116/1521179) enlightening.

Comment: thanks, actually I just want to retrieve information/metadata from videos in my hard disk(they have been extracted from capture packets) . they are complete or incomplete videos. I 'm not going to retrieve information/metadata from Internet